# Namespace NPOI.POIFS.Crypt

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I installed NPOI from NuGet, version 2.1.3. I want to read encrypted excel file. By this goal according to this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f37ed36-92ae-4b43-9229-285e33a32144/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-with-npoi?forum=csharpgeneral) i need use class **EncryptionInfo** from namespace **NPOI.POIFS.Crypt**. But my assembly not contain this namespace.

If you look at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/tree/2.1.3/main/POIFS/Crypt) for this library, you will see this namespace in version 2.1.3.

What is my error?

P.S. Sorry for my english language